# Where should one restart `simple_one_for_one`'s children?

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have an Erlang app where I have a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor that supervises a set of processes that watch for changes on web pages (one URL per child).

I start the children that should be active in my application behaviour's `start` function, after having added the supervisor in question to the app's top supervisor (along with some other processes). Children are then started and stopped dynamically as entries are added/removed (and the entries are persisted to a DB).

If this `simple_one_for_one` supervisor crashes because too many of its children crash (e.g. due to a network issue), the supervisor itself is restarted, but its children are lost. At this point I want to check the DB and start the children that should be active again.

But, how should I restart the children? How can I tell that the supervisor restarted? Should I schedule starting the children from the supervisor's own `start_link` function? Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a supervisor above this which manages it?

Comment: @CallamDelaney Not sure what you mean. If I have a supervisor above the `simple_one_for_one` supervisor (I already do – a `one_for_one` supervisor that also supervises some other things), how should that supervisor know when to restart the `simple_one_for_one` supervisor's children?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the restart strategy of the `simple_one_for_one` supervisor to

```
#{strategy => simple_one_for_one,
                 intensity => 0,
                 period => 1}
```

2. Change the child's (the process watching for changes in web pages) `terminate/2` method to

```
terminate(normal, _State) ->
  %% process terminated normally
  ok;
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
  %% spawn the child again
  do_supverisor_start_child(),
  ok.
```